# Analyze json in twitter feed using pig

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have downloaded 1GB worth of tweets and would like to analyze the same using pig, how can I read the json format of tweets using PIG, I am learning PIG and any pointers would be of immense help.
People talk about using PigJsonLoader(), but that is not part of piggybank.

Comment: I was able to find the way,   A = LOAD 'tweets.json' using JsonLoader('created_at:chararray, text:chararray,id:chararray,id_str:chararray');   ..but not yet fully solved it, since I would like to pick some specific fields from the tweets, would not like to specify every field in the schema

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bound to PiggyBank? You can use ElephantBird's com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.JsonStringToMap which can help you do things slightly more dynamically. It won't solve all of your problems (bags for instance) but it's easy to work with.